# Normalize API response in React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently writing a React application that fetches data from an API. The API response contains lots and lots of fields I currently don't need in my application, so I don't want to store these fields in the state of my application.

I've read in the Redux documentation about [paularmstrong/normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) which can be used to normalize JSON Objects, but seems to be focused to flatten the tree while I need something to basically filter it.

Is there an elegant and performant way to filter the API response?

Currently I am doing it like this, after fetching

```
this.setState= ({
    headline: response.foo.bar.baz.headline,
    text: response.foo.bar.qux[0].text,
    type: response.abc.foo.bar.baz.qux.baz
});
```

While this works, it's really cumbersome and hard to read, so I am searching for a neater way to do it.

Comment: Can you make a function
```a = (response) => {
  return {
    headline: ..,
    ...
  };
}```

Comment: Just a side note. You don't really want `this.setState={}` to be an assignment you want `this.setState(...)` to be a function call

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Sven As of the question itself. How do you imagine the best possible syntax for doing such a transformation to look like? The example looks too heterogeneos to see a pattern. I'd say that the best possible option is to filter data serverside: less traffic, less null checks and such.

Comment: is your request out to your own backend.  if so, [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/) may be a good option for you. If not, you may consider destructing the response in variables before calling `setState` like so `const { headline, qux: { baz }   } = response.foo.bar.baz;`